# Rename multiple choice option sets

Tags: custom-fields, activity, multiple-choice

I'm fairly new to using Civi (building with it on a WordPress site) I'm creating a load of custom fields for several new activities that we need to replicate forms we use. I've created a multiple option set for one of the questions which I want to re-use for the other fields/questions I create. The option set has been labelled as the question I've created, which I can identify it by this when reusing it, but is there a way to rename the multiple choice option sets something more generic to make them more identifiable to other users? or will it always have to be labelled as one of the visible fields?

Example: How often do you use helpdesk service? With mutiple options of none of the time/rarely/some of the time/often/all of the time - the next question might be How often do you use sale service? which I want to use the same multiple choice options but they are showing with the label of How often do you use helpdesk service? Could them options be saved as a set called say "service frequency" to then make it identifiable for all forms that need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom field with the same name that you want for the option_group, then the option_group would have your friendly name and you can select this for your existing and new fields. You don't do anything else with the special custom field and you could hide it in a suitably named custom group.

Better than editing the database I think.

Comment: Thanks Mick, that seems to work I didn't think the option group would still be selectable if disabling the field but they still seem to be there so could do that :)
Have you come across this issue before please? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40023/custom-field-alignment - It points to a theme conflict but disabling the theme hasn't made a difference, thanks

Comment: Not really, but I'll make a comment on your other question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same set of options for two different custom fields, all you need to do is when creating custom field click on 'Reuse an existing set', select the option from the drop down list and save.

Comment: Hi, that's what i've been doing but the label of the custom set is the question and i want to know if it's possible to call the sets something more generic to make them easier to identify or do they 'have' to be labelled as another visible field? thanks

Comment: i understand Cirrus' point that being able to give a much used option_group a generic name would be helpful. In the table civicrm_option_group there is both a name and a title field. is there a reason why the title field could not be edited in the db without anything breaking?

Comment: Thanks yes it would make them more identifiable but I just wanted to check that out the box that is to be expected that you have to reuse a set which is called a visible field (ie there isn't an admin menu somewhere where they are all stored you can add something more generic too?)