# Custom field alignment

Tags: wordpress, contacts, custom-fields

I've created some custom field sets for my contacts which work as expected but when viewing the contact record the display for radio buttons and checkboxes is slightly out in that the box is in some cases closer to the next option in the set. Can this be changed atall or any other workaround to get the alignment more accurate? thanks
[image]

CivCRM 5.38.0 (automatic theme) on a WordPress site (Divi Theme)

Comment: Which Civi theme and CMS theme are you using? A screen shot would help.

Comment: Hi Aidan I've added a screenshot in and the version, thanks :)

Comment: as Aidan implied, this is likely to be a theme issue so if you add your themes for WP and Civi to your Q you may get a more specific answer

Comment: Thanks sorry I misread, I have added the info :)

Comment: This seems to point to a theme conflict but disabling the theme hasn't made a difference, any more suggestions please? thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "automatic theme" do you mean CiviCRM as it comes out of the box. I see from the developer doc that its possible to install a Civi theme (I'm aware of Shoreditch but think its only for Drupal). I just use one of the basic WordPress theme (Twenty-Seventeen). I do think that the layout of radio buttons and checkboxes is sometimes they look closer to the wrong text. I think its a general issue (with WordPress) and don't know it is with Drupal. You might want to look at the demo/sandbox sites and see how it behaves there. https://civicrm.org/demo at the bottom of the page

Comment: Try previewing the custom field set "Donor Information" on the WP demo site (can't tell what the theme is). Its much neater on the Drupal demo site.